# How can I create dynamically a TextView simultaneously in two activities in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I have two activities, in activityOne the user will dynamically create textViews and I want that in the same time to dynamically create textViews with the same content inside activityTwo.
For example:
In activityOne the user will dynamically create a textView "Groceries" I want that in the same time in activityTwo to be dynamically created a textView with the same name: "Groceries".

Comment: how do you dynamically create the textboxes ?send code to be assisted

Comment: You can create a data repository class that contains a `MutableLiveData<String>` field. You can then add observers to the TextViews you want to dynamically update. The data repository class is where you would post changes to the data. I recommend making the data repository class a singleton class for easy access throughout your app.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept an answer (tick the check-mark next to an answer) if it answers your question. In this way your question stops to show up as _unanswered_. Also up-vote good answers. – As you're starting out here, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and have a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a data repository class as such

```
public class DataRepository {

    private static final DataRepository INSTANCE = new DataRepository();

    private final MutableLiveData<String> text = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public void updateText(String newText){
        text.setValue(newText);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<String> getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public static DataRepository getInstance(){
        return INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

You can then listen to changes on the data using an `Observer` like so

```
DataRepository dataRepository = DataRepository.getInstance();
dataRepository.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(String newText) {
        textView.setText(newText);
    }
});
```

Where `this` refers to the Activity.

To update the text, simply call

```
DataRepository dataRepository = DataRepository.getInstance();
dataRepository.updateText("New text");
```

From anywhere in your program. The observers will update everything for you automatically.